# How to save an image permanently on Flutter after picking from Gallery or Camera? Am getting this error when am setting the picked image

Tags: flutter

Am getting this error when am setting the picked image, future dynamic is not a subtype of string.

This is how am setting the image

[image]

This is how am saving the image path using shared preferences
[image]

Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because getImagePathFromSharedPreferences doesn't return String?, it returns a Future

you either handle the async task in the initState or use a FutureBuilder

**make sure to set the return type of getImagePathFromSharedPreferences**

```
Future<String?> getImagePathFromSharedPreferences() async {
   // ...
}
```

I'm gonna use FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder<String?>(
  future: getImagePathFromSharedPreferences(),
  initialData: null,
  builder: (
      BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot,
      ) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else if (!snapshot.hasError) {
      return CircleAvatar(
        radius: 45.0,
        backgroundImage: _imageFile != null
          ? Image.file(_imageFile).image
          : snapshot.hasData
            ? FileImage(snapshot.data!)
            : AssetImage(_imageUrl),
      );
    } else {
      return const Text('Error');
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: Hello, this works but don't forget to set the FileImage to be of type File i.e FileImage(File(snapshot.data))